# PhpStorm 2019.3.4 External Tools the input device is not a TTY. If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'

Tags: docker, phpstorm, laradock

I'm using [Laradock](https://laradock.io/), now I want to set up External Tools in my PhpStorm 2019.3.4 so that it's easy for me to run the command and no extra effort to type it. But I get unexpected error:

> the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'

Note: I am using Windows 10

Here is how I setup

**Tools Settings:**

> Program: `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-compose.exe`
>   Arguments: `exec workspace bash`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

External tools console is non-TTY (related feature request: [IDEA-103276](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-103276)); and docker commands are by default allocating a TTY (https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/)

Enabling `COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI` (https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_interactive_no_cli) is a workaround, but it doesn't work on Windows:(